# xticklabels misaligned

Tags: pgfplots

Please consider the following MWE. The same code is in another document with a larger preamble, so maybe my problem with the misaligned `xticklabels` is because of conflicting `packages`.

The first screenshot shows the results of the MWE and the second how it looks like when compiled with a larger preamble.

[image: As is should be]
[image: Misaligned <code>xticklabels</code>]

**Note:** For the MWE I did not include special formatting (e.g. colours, dashing etc).

**EDIT** By the way: If you take a look at the data in `dataLevelerConverter2.dat` you will see that there is a Kalenderwoche 42. However, in the first screenshot it seems that the `xticks` start with Kalenderwoche 43.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\begin{filecontents}{dataLevelerConverter2.dat}
Wert    Kalenderwochen  Nachfrage   Nachfrage1a Nachfrage1b Nachfrage1c Nachfrage1d nachLeveler nachConverter
1   42  nan nan nan nan nan 128 608
2   43  255 255 nan nan nan 1088    608
3   44  1584    1584    1584    nan nan 960 1265
4   45  1296    nan 1296    1296    nan 1570    1265
5   46  432 nan nan 432 nan 610 610
6   47  972 nan nan 972 nan 610 610
7   48  540 nan nan 540 nan 610 610
8   49  1104    nan nan 1104    1104    610 610
9   50  0   nan nan nan 0   0   0
\end{filecontents}


%%%%Some number formatting for pgfplots%%%%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,%additional code
      use comma,%additional code
       1000 sep={\,},%additional code
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=10cm,
        height=6cm,
        xticklabels from table = {dataLevelerConverter2.dat}{Kalenderwochen},
        xtick from table = {dataLevelerConverter2.dat}{Wert},
%        xtick = {1,...,9},
%        xtick = data,
        xlabel=Kalenderwoche,
        ylabel=Kundennachfrage,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north,draw=none},
        legend columns=3
]

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=Nachfrage] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label1}

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=nachLeveler] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label2}

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=nachConverter] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label3}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are probably supplying the tick labels manually and the remaning ones are left empty because it runs out of tick labels on the list. Without any other info we can't say much.

Comment: @percusse: The code for the plot is for both, the MWE and the larger tex-document the same. I do not supply any special information for the tick labels. (Hope I understood you correctly)

Comment: @John: Thanks for putting together a complete compilable example. The only thing missing is that you need to include enough of the preamble so that the MWE here reproduce the problem. Not sure how we can possibly guess what other settings are causing the problem.

Comment: As @PeterGrill mentions, we are trying to guess here and you see our success rate already. Try to comment out pgfplots related parts and see what is causing the change. There is groupplots in your MWE so that might be another guess that some other plot style is effecting it etc.

Comment: @PeterGrill `xtick={1,...,9}` seemed to be the missing code but I would like to retrieve this information form my dat-file which includes the information in the first column. `xtick from table = {dataLevelerConverter2.dat}{Wert}` does not to work, though.

Comment: I don't think there is a ` xtick from table` key. The `xticklabels from table` already specifies where to get the tick mars from. If you want the x ticks to use the other column just specify that in the `xticklabels from table`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I would like to use the labels of column "Kalenderwochen" but LaTeX seems to need the information which is included in column "Wert" to place the labels correctly. Very odd that I cannot retrieve the information from my dat-file and that instead I need to provide the information manually by `xtick={1,...,9}`.

Comment: You don't need to read the `xticklabels` from the table. Just set `x=Kalenderwochen` in the `addplot` options. If you need more ticks, add `try min ticks=9` in the `axis` options. This will change the `yticks` too, so you can set `ytick={0,500,...,1500}` if you want to preserve the `yticks`.

Comment: @Luigi: "Kalenderwochen" translates to "calendar weeks", so these will wrap around, so just using `x=Kalenderwochen` might work for this concrete example, but is not the "proper" thing to do for this kind of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luigi's suggestion of using `Kalenderwochen` as the x-coordinate directly is a good idea in this concrete example. However, it won't work if `Kalenderwochen` indeed contains labels (numeric or otherwise): In John's text label example, the `xtick={0,...,9}` has to be set explicitly. Usually, one could just use `xtick=data`, but that only works if there are no `nan`s in the first plot.

So, for the rare case where you need to provide labels from a table but can't use `xtick=data` to make sure the ticks and ticklabels are synchronised, here's a style `xtick from table` that works analogously to `xticklabels from data`:

[image]

---

This approach has the drawback that you're always using all ticks and ticklabels, instead of letting PGFPlots determine the appropriate number of ticks. To fix this, you can set

```
    xticklabel={%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\datarow{round(\tick)}%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\datarow}{Kalenderwochen}\of{dataLevelerConverter2.dat}%
        \pgfplotsretval%
    }
```

which will get the appropriate tick label for each tick position from the data table.

[image]

---

Code for the first example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    xticks from table/.code 2 args={%
        \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplotstabletotalrows{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \edef\ticklist{}
            \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#2}\of#1\as\cell{%
                \edef\ticklist{\ticklist\cell\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<\pgfplotstabletotalrows,\fi}
            }
        \pgfplotsset{xtick=\ticklist}
    },
}


\begin{filecontents}{dataLevelerConverter2.dat}
Wert    Kalenderwochen  Nachfrage   Nachfrage1a Nachfrage1b Nachfrage1c Nachfrage1d nachLeveler nachConverter
1   42  nan nan nan nan nan 128 608
2   43  255 255 nan nan nan 1088    608
3   44  1584    1584    1584    nan nan 960 1265
4   45  1296    nan 1296    1296    nan 1570    1265
5   46  432 nan nan 432 nan 610 610
6   47  972 nan nan 972 nan 610 610
7   48  540 nan nan 540 nan 610 610
8   49  1104    nan nan 1104    1104    610 610
9   50  0   nan nan nan 0   0   0
10   51  255 255 nan nan nan 1088    608
11   52  1584    1584    1584    nan nan 960 1265
12   1  1296    nan 1296    1296    nan 1570    1265
\end{filecontents}


%%%%Some number formatting for pgfplots%%%%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,%additional code
      use comma,%additional code
       1000 sep={\,},%additional code
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=10cm,
        height=6cm,
        xticklabels from table = {dataLevelerConverter2.dat}{Kalenderwochen},
        xticks from table = {dataLevelerConverter2.dat}{Wert},
        xlabel=Kalenderwoche,
        ylabel=Kundennachfrage,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north,draw=none},
        legend columns=3
]

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=Nachfrage] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label1}

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=nachLeveler] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label2}

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=nachConverter] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label3}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Code for the second example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    xticks from table/.code 2 args={%
        \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplotstabletotalrows{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \edef\ticklist{}
            \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#2}\of#1\as\cell{%
                \edef\ticklist{\ticklist\cell\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<\pgfplotstabletotalrows,\fi}
            }
        \pgfplotsset{xtick=\ticklist}
    },
}


\begin{filecontents}{dataLevelerConverter2.dat}
Wert    Kalenderwochen  Nachfrage   Nachfrage1a Nachfrage1b Nachfrage1c Nachfrage1d nachLeveler nachConverter
1   42  nan nan nan nan nan 128 608
2   43  255 255 nan nan nan 1088    608
3   44  1584    1584    1584    nan nan 960 1265
4   45  1296    nan 1296    1296    nan 1570    1265
5   46  432 nan nan 432 nan 610 610
6   47  972 nan nan 972 nan 610 610
7   48  540 nan nan 540 nan 610 610
8   49  1104    nan nan 1104    1104    610 610
9   50  0   nan nan nan 0   0   0
10   51  255 255 nan nan nan 1088    608
11   52  1584    1584    1584    nan nan 960 1265
12   1  1296    nan 1296    1296    nan 1570    1265
\end{filecontents}


%%%%Some number formatting for pgfplots%%%%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,%additional code
      use comma,%additional code
       1000 sep={\,},%additional code
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=6cm,
        height=6cm,
        enlargelimits=false,
        xticklabel={%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\datarow{round(\tick)}%
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\datarow}{Kalenderwochen}\of{dataLevelerConverter2.dat}%
            \pgfplotsretval%
        },
        xlabel=Kalenderwoche,
        ylabel=Kundennachfrage,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north,draw=none},
        legend columns=3
]

    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=Nachfrage] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label1}

    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=nachLeveler] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label2}

    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=nachConverter] {dataLevelerConverter2.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label3}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake There is one problem with your approach. If you lower the width to, for instance 6cm, the tick labels get to close/overlap. How must one change your code so that LaTeX only plots such a number of tick labels so that they do not overlap. (e.g. with `width=6cm` it would be better to have only `{42,44,...,1}` as `ticklabels`.

Comment: @John: Fair point. I've added a different approach that allows you to use PGFPlots normal tick placement algorithm or to manually select which ticks are placed.

Answer (score 0):

@Luigi and @Jake are right.

**xticklabels are numbers**

I wanted to use the column `Kalenderwochen` in `dataLevelerConverter2.dat` as `xticklabels`. As this column contains numbers I can write

```
\addplot table [x=Kalenderwochen, y=Nachfrage]
```

instead of

```
\addplot table [x=Wert, y=Nachfrage]
```

and delete

```
xticklabels from table = {dataLevelerConverter2.dat}{Kalenderwochen}
```

**xticklabels are not numbers**

In the case the column `Kalenderwochen` contains other information than numbers (e.g. "first data set", "second data set") one must write

```
\addplot table [x=Wert, y=Nachfrage]
xticklabels from table = {dataLevelerConverter2.dat}{Kalenderwochen}
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\begin{filecontents}{Numbers.dat}
Wert    Kalenderwochen  Nachfrage   Nachfrage1a Nachfrage1b Nachfrage1c Nachfrage1d nachLeveler nachConverter
1   42  nan nan nan nan nan 128 608
2   43  255 255 nan nan nan 1088    608
3   44  1584    1584    1584    nan nan 960 1265
4   45  1296    nan 1296    1296    nan 1570    1265
5   46  432 nan nan 432 nan 610 610
6   47  972 nan nan 972 nan 610 610
7   48  540 nan nan 540 nan 610 610
8   49  1104    nan nan 1104    1104    610 610
9   50  0   nan nan nan 0   0   0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Strings.dat}
Wert    Kalenderwochen  Nachfrage   Nachfrage1a Nachfrage1b Nachfrage1c Nachfrage1d nachLeveler nachConverter
1   first  nan nan nan nan nan 128 608
2   second  255 255 nan nan nan 1088    608
3   third  1584    1584    1584    nan nan 960 1265
4   fourth  1296    nan 1296    1296    nan 1570    1265
5   fifth  432 nan nan 432 nan 610 610
6   sixth  972 nan nan 972 nan 610 610
7   seventh  540 nan nan 540 nan 610 610
8   eighth  1104    nan nan 1104    1104    610 610
9   ninth  0   nan nan nan 0   0   0
\end{filecontents}

%%%%Some number formatting for pgfplots%%%%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,%additional code
      use comma,%additional code
       1000 sep={\,},%additional code
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=10cm,
        height=6cm,
        xlabel=Kalenderwoche,
        ylabel=Kundennachfrage,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north,draw=none},
        legend columns=3
]

    \addplot table [x=Kalenderwochen, y=Nachfrage] {Numbers.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label1}

    \addplot table [x=Kalenderwochen, y=nachLeveler] {Numbers.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label2}

    \addplot table [x=Kalenderwochen, y=nachConverter] {Numbers.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label3}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=10cm,
        height=6cm,
        xticklabels from table = {Strings.dat}{Kalenderwochen},
        xtick = {1,...,9},
        xticklabel style={rotate=90},
        xlabel=Kalenderwoche,
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
        ylabel=Kundennachfrage,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north,draw=none},
        legend columns=3
]

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=Nachfrage] {Strings.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label1}

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=nachLeveler] {Strings.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label2}

    \addplot table [x=Wert, y=nachConverter] {Strings.dat} ;
        \addlegendentry{label3}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem in your question? By the way, you don't need the first column in your table: you can simply use `x expr=\coordindex` in the `addplot` options, along with `xtick={0,...,8}` (you have to load the `pgfplotstable` package too).